# access certain folder in azure cloud service

Tags: azure

In my code (which has worker role) I need to specify a path to a directory (third party library requires it). Locally I've included folder into project and just give full path to it. However after deployment of course I need a new path. How do I confirm that whole folder has been deployed and how do I determine a new path to it?

**Edit:**
I added folder to the role node in visual studio and accessed it like this: `Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot"), "my_folder");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this directory be used for reading and writing?  If yes, you should use a LocalStorage resource.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-local-storage-resources/ shows how to use this.

If the directory is only for reading (ie. you have binaries or config files there), then you can use the %RoleRoot% environment variable to identify the path where your package was deployed to, then just append whatever folder you refernced in your project (ie. %RoleRoot%\Myfiles).

Comment: the link is no longer valid

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a slightly different approach. Place the 3rd party package into Windows Azure blob storage, then during role startup, you can download/extract it and place the files into the available Local storage (giving it whatever permissions the app needs). Then leverage that location from your application via the same local storage configuration entry.

This should help you reduce the size of your deployment package as well as give you the ability to update the 3rd party components without completely redeploying your solution. And by leveraging it on startup, you can guarantee that the files will be there in case the role instance gets torn down and rebuilt.

Comment: Reducing deployment size sounds attractive, I'll explore this approach.